# Setting up a SSTP VPN on Windows Server 2012 behind a router

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I've searched for similar topics, but I'm having some trouble finding info on this particular task. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a router with a static external (WAN) IP and hostname. On the private network behind the router, I have my web server. On that server I'm running Windows Server 2012. That server gets assigned a static IP by the router.

Here's what I have so far:

- I want to set up SSTP, so I have forwarded port 443 on the router to the server's address
- I have installed the "Remote Access" roles on the server
- I have gone through the configuration wizard in the "Routing and Remote Access" client to set up a VPN-only.
- I have installed a self-signed 2048 bit SSL certificate on the server.

I think what I'm missing is the user configuration. How do I set username/password combinations to use on the VPN? I've read something about installing Active Directory Domain Services, but then it wants me to install a domain controller, a DNS, and so on (I don't even have/want a domain name for my internal network, I just want to be able to access my network drives while I'm away from home!). That seems far more complex than it should be, so what is my next step in getting this thing working?

Comment: I believe that Windows Home Server would provide this access in a simple way. But I don't believe that it's sold anymore. There is 2012 essentials but it's a lot more expensive than Home Server was.


It sounds like you need an openvpn. It's now built in to many openwrt routers or can be installed as an addon package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have already setup Routing and Remote Access properly.
For authentication, make sure you've created a local group called VPN users and added to your account (this can be done in the Computer Management MMC). Next you need to launch NPS to authorize that group so open up the RRAS console, Under the server, Right-click Network Policies and select New Policy:

Type in a name – select Remote Access Server

Click Add and Click Windows groups

Click Add Groups and type in the name of the group, click next

Select Access Granted > Next

Only Select MS-CHAPv2 > Next

You can configure some timeouts if you require. Click next

Some other options > next

And finally finish to save your Network Access Policy.

So if all is well then you should have a working RRAS Setup that can successfully authenticate any users under VPN groups.